# Convolution of Two Gaussian Functions

Tags: python, fft, convolution

Let us consider two Gaussian functions `f(k)` and `g(k)` in frequency space, where `k` denotes the frequency. I want to perform a numerical convolution of them. We know that the convolution of two Gaussian functions is a Gaussian function. But when I plot, I don't get a Gaussian. My code in Python is as follows.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.style as sty
sty.use(['seaborn-notebook', 'ggplot'])

L = 17.5
N = 48
dx = L/N
dk = 2*np.pi/L
x = np.arange(N)*dx - L/2
k = 2*np.pi * np.fft.fftfreq(N, dx)

alpha = 1
beta = 1

def f(k):
   return np.sqrt(np.pi/alpha) * np.exp(-k**2/(4*alpha))

def g(k):
   return np.sqrt(np.pi/beta) * np.exp(-k**2/(4*beta))

fs = np.array([f(k_) for k_ in k])
gs = np.array([g(k_) for k_ in k])
numconvfg = np.convolve(fs, gs)[:len(k)]

plt.plot(ks, numconvfg)
```

[image]

I have two questions:

**Question 1**

Why I am not getting a Gaussian in the plot? How should I modify the code in order to get a Gaussian in the plot?

**Question 2**

How do I know that I am having aliasing artifacts during the convolution? How can I show the aliasing effect in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting a Gaussian because your `fs` and `gs` lists are not Gaussians.
`np.fft.fftfreq` returns a list of sample frequencies that starts with zero. As a result, your `fs` and `gs` lists start with the values `f(0)` and `g(0)`.

Do a simple sorting

```
zipped = zip(k,fs,gs)
zipped.sort()
k, fs, gs = zip(*zipped)
```

and plot

```
plt.plot(np.convolve(fs, gs))
```

gives you a Gaussian plot:

[image: plot].

You would probably want to be more careful constructing the Gaussians though. To see how well the sampling is, you can plot your functions with data points (`plt.plot(k,fs,'x'`) instead of lines.